# Two package with same name : Eclipse can't resolve import

Tags: java, eclipse

I am working on a existing Java project within Eclipse Oxygen.

I have :

- **Project A "src/main"** that contains an interface "Constant" in package "azerty" (it's an example).
- **Project B "src/test"** that contains an interface also called "Constant" in package also named "azerty". In my **"src/main"** folder (still in project B), I try to import azerty.Constant.

The problem is that Eclipse imports the interface that belongs to project B "src/test" and not project A "src/main".

How can I force Eclipse to use the interface form project A?

PS: I'm not allowed to rename one of those packages.

Answer (score 0):

Check which project is added to your current project.

To add project A interface. Select your current project. Right-click on it-> Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Projects Tab -> Select Project A -> Now Use your Project A interface.

Comment: I'm using maven and project A was already in my dependencies. But still, I tried your solution. When I went to  Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Projects Tab, there was no projects in it so I added Project A. I applied then had to wait because Eclipse was rebuilding my project. Unfortunately, after that, it did not work.

Comment: Ah. Ok. Since you have two package with same names. It's not picking up Project B. Can you try one thing for me. Remove project B from your build path and let Project A remain in the build path. Then create a reference to the class you want from project A. After doing that, again add project B to your build path. Just a suggestion.

Comment: I'll try this, but I'm not sure you entirely understood my setup : I only have 2 projects. A and B. And it's in "src/main" of B that I try to import azerty.Constant of A. Edit : Couldn't do what you suggest... Thanks for trying to help, tho...